# In InDesign CC how do I remove pagination from just the cover page?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I need to remove the pagination from the cover page in InDesign and start pagination  with the second page of the layout.

Comment: `Layout > Numbering & Section options . . .`

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the *Pages* window and there, double-click your master page. In place of the page numbers, you will see a letter. This gets replaced by the page number on actual pages.
2. Select this letter and delete it. Now make sure to have your caret on position to *replace* that character, if you were to type.
3. Go to *Type → Insert Special Character → Markers → Previous Page Number.* This will essentially increment all page numbers by one. So the cover page won't be *1* anymore – the page after it will.
4. Now, go to your cover page in the *Pages* window.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the page number. Now you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok 1 of 3 things you could be talking about...

**Option 1**, changing the document to start with page 2 (typically used for when you're trying to avoid the first page in a "Facing Pages" layout.

[image: FILE > DOCUMENT SETUP]

[image: START PAGE]

**Option 2**, you have your pagination set on your master pages:

Use the selection tool (<kbd>V</kbd>) then hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>(Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>(Windows) while clicking it to unlock the text box.

**Option 3**, you want to leave the pages but want the automatic pages numbers to be set to the following page.

[image: TYPE > INSERT SPECIAL CHARACTERS > MARKERS > NEXT PAGE NUMBER]